# Is there a Spark built-in that flattens nested arrays?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a DataFrame field that is a `Seq[Seq[String]]` I built a UDF to transform said column into a column of Seq[String]; basically, a UDF for the `flatten` function from Scala.

```
def combineSentences(inCol: String, outCol: String): DataFrame => DataFrame = {

    def flatfunc(seqOfSeq: Seq[Seq[String]]): Seq[String] = seqOfSeq match {
        case null => Seq.empty[String]
        case _ => seqOfSeq.flatten
    }
    df: DataFrame => df.withColumn(outCol, udf(flatfunc _).apply(col(inCol)))
}
```

My use case is strings, but obviously, this could be generic. You can use this function in a chain of DataFrame transforms like:

```
df.transform(combineSentences(inCol, outCol))
```

Is there a Spark built-in function that does the same thing? I have not been able to find one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a similar function (since Spark 2.4) and it is called `flatten`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.flatten
```

From [the official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@flatten(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column):

> `def flatten(e: Column): Column`
>
> Creates a single array from an array of arrays. If a structure of nested arrays is deeper than two levels, only one level of nesting is removed.
>
> Since
>
> 2.4.0

To get the exact equivalent you'll have to `coalesce` to replace `NULL`.